# Keyboard shortcut for taking screen shot in Firefox Responsive Design mode?

Tags: firefox, screenshot

Doing a lot of documentation with screen shots and am using Firefox's excellent Responsive Design View (Tools > Web Developer > Responsive Design View) to ensure a consistent browser window size. Is there a keyboard shortcut for taking the screen shot (technically, active browser window contents), or am I limited to clicking the camera icon?

Comment: I have the same problem. A shortcut would be useful. Until I have one I use the console. see http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2015/10/22/firefoxs-screenshot-command/

Comment: I'm interested in finding out how to even fake getting a screenshot, even if it is from the web console, and as long as it is NOT using the mouse, but learned today that it is not even there anymore: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071424/how-to-enable-the-screenshot-command-from-firefox-web-console